# History.js remove active class from list item

Tags: javascript, history.js

Here is what I'm trying to do. Lets say in my AJAX app I click on a link which adds a class called active to the link, this click also triggers the statechange on History.js.

What I need help understanding is how to save the current active link(s) with my current state so when I click on the back or forward button it removes or adds the active class from the link(s) depending on what that state looks like at that particular URL.

Answer (score 0):

I took another look at the problem and think I found a better approach. Before I was adding an active class to my list items on the click event

```
$(".products ul li a").on("click", function(e) {

  $this.closest("li").toggleClass("active");
}
```

But now I think a better way would be to add the active class to my list items when the History statechange event occurs. This would allow me to first retrieve the GET url parameters and then based off those values find list items who's data-value attribute matches the url values.

Here is a breakdown of the steps I think are needed to find the correct matching elements.

1. On the History.js statechange event call the activate_items() method
2. Find if there are any url parameters named "product_cats" or "color" and if so do they have any values.
3. Grab a jquery collection of list items
4. Check if each list item in the collection has a data attribute called "value" that matches one of the URL parameter values.
5. If there is a match then add the active class to the list item
6. Remove active class if there is not a match

Here is an example of my url parameters. So I have 2 arguments both with multiple values. 
**localhost/mytheme/?product_cats=17,60&color=13,14**

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(e){ 
   activate_items();
}

// GET PARAMETER
function get_parameter( name ){

    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var state = History.getState();
    var current_url = state.cleanUrl;
    var results = regex.exec( current_url );

    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else {
        return results[1];
    }   
}

// ACTIVATE ITEMS
function activate_items( url ){

    var items;

    // Categories
    var cats = get_parameter("product_cats");
    var colors = get_parameter("color");
    if (cats.length > 0) {
        items = jQuery(".product ul li a");

        // Check each <li> for a match. If its data-value attribute matches 
        // one of the values from cats than add an active class to the <li>
    };
    if (colors.length > 0) {
        items = jQuery(".product ul li a");

        // Check each <li> for a match. If its data-value attribute matches 
        // one of the values from colors than add an active class to the <li>
    };
}
```

You can see in the code that I haven't figured out how to do the matching yet.

To reiterate I am doing all of this so when you hit the back and forward or refresh buttons on the browser the list items will have the correct active state depending on the URL parameters. I am open to any direction even a completely different approach to this problem.